# How to create a long lived cassandra CqlSession in a Javalin app

Tags: cassandra, datastax, javalin

I have an app built with Javalin (a simple HTTP framework in Java) that leverages Cassandra as the backend.

According to Datastax docs https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.9/manual/core/#quick-start

> CqlSession is the main entry point of the driver. It holds the known state of the actual Cassandra cluster, and is what you use to execute queries. It is thread-safe, you should create a single instance (per target Cassandra cluster), and share it throughout your application;

This is what my `main` function looks like:

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CqlSession cqlSession = CqlSession.builder().build();
    runCassandraMigration(cqlSession);
    Javalin app =
        Javalin.create(config -> config.registerPlugin(new OpenApiPlugin(getOpenApiOptions())))
            .start(PORT);
    Handlers handlers = new Handlers(cqlSession);
    registerAppRoutes(app, handlers);
  }
```

The `Handlers` class include handle function like below:

```java
public class Handlers {
  private final CqlSession session;
  
  public Context getAllUsers(Context ctx) {
    ResultSet rs = session.execute("select * from my_status.users");
    List<Row> rows = rs.all();
    return ctx.json(rows.stream().map(this::rowToUser).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  }
}
```

However, after I start the application, and hit the REST endpoint locally, I got

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session is closed
```

I want to know how to create a long-lived `CqlSession` rather than per-request short-lived ones. The app I am working on can be found in https://github.com/YikSanChan/mystatus/tree/main/api/src/main/java.

Comment: The code on that GitHub repo doesn't look like what you posted. I believe that the code you posted should work fine. The session isn't being closed so I don't think it is possible to even get that exception in that case, are you sure that you weren't using something like "try (CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder().build()) { }"?

Comment: @Yik Scan Chan did you fixed your problem?

Comment: @JadChahine I didn't. Still haven't figured out